# find files with specific text and remove that text

Tags: php, linux, command-line, ssh

Is it possible to search files in server using command line which contains defined text. e.g. "this was hacked by slacker!" and remove that sentence only?

Also, how can that be prevented in future, not sure how they can add text in every single file.

Comment: This seems like more of a [Super User](http://superuser.com) / [Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) question.

Comment: I'd perform a web search for "sed one liners" and find a relevant example.

Comment: It is easy to pipe `find` and `sed -i` to remove lines from files. However, if you've been hacked, you should probably restore from known-good backups instead. As for preventing future hacks, you should definitely practice the principle of least authority with your permissions and consider using a [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/)

Comment: What you got so far? Are you trying to do this with php and are you using ssh too? Here's about ssh with php http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

Comment: may be restoring would be safer option but it was good to know that it can be done using SED. i thought may be just few files from initial scan and tried to compare and replace but advanced scanner found that every single php files were altered. I am going to play around with sed on free time which would be helpful for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed

http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html